# Context menu in list activity

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I have list activity with custom array adapter and I can't to get context menu when make long press on list item.

```
<TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

    </FrameLayout>
```

list item layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally = "true"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            />


    <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:gravity="right"
            >
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"                
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"


                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);



  }
```

Why I do not see context menu? What I do wrong? How to get context menu with array adapter and ListActivity.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom ListView and context menu. How to get it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972945/custom-listview-and-context-menu-how-to-get-it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property LongClickable for the first LinearLayout from list item layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:longClickable="true"
        >
...
```